# Can Google App Engine Standard environment connect to a GRPC service?

Tags: python, grpc, google-app-engine-python

I have an application with a front-end running in App Engine Standard written in python. I want it to connect to a GRPC middleware service. In other words, this is what I want to do:

```
[ Client ] --(http)--> [ App Engine Std ] --(grpc)--> [ Middleware ]
```

I know App Engine has a lot of restrictions for what you can do. I've searched throughly over the documentation and other forums and was unable to find an answer. To clarify, I'm not trying to put a GRPC server *in* app engine, but to access one *from* AE.

Is this something App Engine can do?

Comment: What features does GRPC have that make you doubt it being supported in Standard Environment?? From there I can answer, because I do not familiar with GRPC.

Answer (score 0):

You should have no problem doing this and should be no different from making an network call to external services. The only thing I think you should watch out for is the firewall restrictions on egress traffic.